Auto OPTIMIZE causing a data discrepancy
I have a delta table in Azure Databricks that gets MERGEd every 10 minutes.
In the below screenshot:

in the version history of this table, I see a MERGE operation every 10 minutes which is expected. Along with that, I see the OPTIMIZE operation after every 3-4 runs, this article suggests that Databricks does the predictive optimization for the tables, and that is the reason that I see those OPTIMIZE operations.
My question: When I run a simple SELECT statement on this table with some basic WHERE clause, I randomly see data discrepency (fewer records than expected). To dig dipper into this, I noted the time when I ran the query and got fewer records and then I queried the history of the table for that time. It seems like when it performs the OPTIMIZE it is combining the smaller files to form a bigger file but I am getting caught in the middle and there's a discrepancy which defeats the ACID properties that Databricks offers.
This is the operation metrics of the OPTIMIZE operation:
numRemovedFiles: "2"
numRemovedBytes: "5644151"
p25FileSize: "3234772"
numDeletionVectorsRemoved: "1"
minFileSize: "3234772"
numAddedFiles: "1"
maxFileSize: "3234772"
p75FileSize: "3234772"
p50FileSize: "3234772"
numAddedBytes: "3234772"

and this is the operation metrics of the MERGE operation that ran 10 seconds earlier:
numTargetRowsCopied: "0"
numTargetRowsDeleted: "0"
numTargetFilesAdded: "1"
numTargetBytesAdded: "2409613"
numTargetBytesRemoved: "0"
numTargetDeletionVectorsAdded: "1"
numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated: "20380"
executionTimeMs: "22332"
materializeSourceTimeMs: "5886"
numTargetRowsInserted: "6"
numTargetRowsMatchedDeleted: "0"
numTargetDeletionVectorsUpdated: "0"
scanTimeMs: "1781"
numTargetRowsUpdated: "20380"
numOutputRows: "20386"
numTargetDeletionVectorsRemoved: "0"
numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceUpdated: "0"
numTargetChangeFilesAdded: "1"
numSourceRows: "20386"
numTargetFilesRemoved: "0"
numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceDeleted: "0"
rewriteTimeMs: "14510"

What could be the reason for this data discrepency and is there any setting that I am missing in these operations?

What results you are getting and what is the expected results? add them in question

I am getting fewer records from that table (~700) whereas I expect almost 2000+ records. As mentioned in the question, I think I am getting caught in the middle and when the OPTIMIZE is running it is providing the lesser data. I hope that clears the confusion.

As you mentioned, Databricks performs predictive optimization on Delta tables, which involves combining smaller files into larger ones to improve query performance.
Also, it could be posssible that you are running your SELECT statement at a time when the OPTIMIZE operation is in progress, which could cause the issue.
You can try the below :
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite", "false")
spark.sql("OPTIMIZE delta.`/FileStore/tables/delta/sample1`")

Results:
DataFrame[path: string, metrics: struct<numFilesAdded:bigint,numFilesRemoved:bigint,filesAdded:struct<min:bigint,max:bigint,avg:double,totalFiles:bigint,totalSize:bigint>,filesRemoved:struct<min:bigint,max:bigint,avg:double,totalFiles:bigint,totalSize:bigint>,partitionsOptimized:bigint,zOrderStats:struct<strategyName:string,inputCubeFiles:struct<num:bigint,size:bigint>,inputOtherFiles:struct<num:bigint,size:bigint>,inputNumCubes:bigint,mergedFiles:struct<num:bigint,size:bigint>,numOutputCubes:bigint,mergedNumCubes:bigint>,clusteringStats:struct<inputZCubeFiles:struct<numFiles:bigint,size:bigint>,inputOtherFiles:struct<numFiles:bigint,size:bigint>,inputNumZCubes:bigint,mergedFiles:struct<numFiles:bigint,size:bigint>,numOutputZCubes:bigint>,numBins:bigint,numBatches:bigint,totalConsideredFiles:bigint,totalFilesSkipped:bigint,preserveInsertionOrder:boolean,numFilesSkippedToReduceWriteAmplification:bigint,numBytesSkippedToReduceWriteAmplification:bigint,startTimeMs:bigint,endTimeMs:bigint,totalClusterParallelism:bigint,totalScheduledTasks:bigint,autoCompactParallelismStats:struct<maxClusterActiveParallelism:bigint,minClusterActiveParallelism:bigint,maxSessionActiveParallelism:bigint,minSessionActiveParallelism:bigint>,deletionVectorStats:struct<numDeletionVectorsRemoved:bigint,numDeletionVectorRowsRemoved:bigint>,numTableColumns:bigint,numTableColumnsWithStats:bigint,totalTaskExecutionTimeMs:bigint,skippedArchivedFiles:bigint,clusteringMetrics:struct<sizeOfTableInBytesBeforeLazyClustering:bigint,isNewMetadataCreated:boolean,isPOTriggered:boolean,numFilesSkippedWithoutStats:bigint,numFilesClassifiedToIntermediateNodes:bigint,sizeOfFilesClassifiedToIntermediateNodesInBytes:bigint,logicalSizeOfFilesClassifiedToIntermediateNodesInBytes:bigint,numFilesClassifiedToLeafNodes:bigint,sizeOfFilesClassifiedToLeafNodesInBytes:bigint,logicalSizeOfFilesClassifiedToLeafNodesInBytes:bigint,numThreadsForClassifier:int,clusterThresholdStrategy:string,minFileSize:bigint,maxFileSize:bigint,nodeMinNumFilesToCompact:bigint,numIdealFiles:bigint,numClusteringTasksPlanned:int,numCompactionTasksPlanned:int,numOptimizeBatchesPlanned:int,numLeafNodesExpanded:bigint,numLeafNodesClustered:bigint,numGetFilesForNodeCalls:bigint,numSamplingJobs:bigint,numLeafNodesCompacted:bigint,numIntermediateNodesCompacted:bigint,totalSizeOfDataToCompactInBytes:bigint,totalLogicalSizeOfDataToCompactInBytes:bigint,numIntermediateNodesClustered:bigint,numFilesSkippedAfterExpansion:bigint,totalSizeOfFilesSkippedAfterExpansionInBytes:bigint,totalLogicalSizeOfFilesSkippedAfterExpansionInBytes:bigint,totalSizeOfDataToRewriteInBytes:bigint,totalLogicalSizeOfDataToRewriteInBytes:bigint,timeMetrics:struct<classifierTimeMs:bigint,optimizerTimeMs:bigint,metadataLoadTimeMs:bigint,totalGetFilesForNodeCallsTimeMs:bigint,totalSamplingTimeMs:bigint,metadataCreationTimeMs:bigint>,maxOptimizeBatchesInParallel:bigint,currentIteration:int,maxIterations:int,clusteringStrategy:string>>]

Setting the delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite configuration parameter to false we can disabled automatic optimization
Then, manually trigger optimization using the OPTIMIZE command.
Also, you can also set the the maximum file size for optimized files to 1 GB & Optimize the Delta table.
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.maxFileSize", "1000000000")
spark.sql("OPTIMIZE delta.`/FileStore/tables/delta/sample1` ZORDER BY (id)")


Hi Dileep, Thank you for the response. When you say "Also, it could be posssible that you are running your SELECT statement at a time when the OPTIMIZE operation is in progress, which could cause the issue." do we have any official documentation suggesting this? Logically, I think this is the problem but some official doc would help here. FYI - I will be raising this to Databricks as well so we might get some response from them on this.
